# Multi Threading is not working in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

In my application what i am doing is that, creating multiple **Service** classes.

From my main Activity i want to call this **Service** classes using Threads.

But what is happening in my application is that,when i Start  first thread for calling First Service its works perfectly, but when i try-to call another service class by creating new Thread its not called at all.

Here is my activity code,

```
public void startService(View v)
{
    Thread t= new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {

            Intent inte= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IntentService_Demo.class);
            startService(inte);
        }

    };
    t.start();

}

public void startService_2(View v)
{

    Thread t2= new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.e("1", "Clicked_2");
            Intent inte2= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IntentService_Demo_2.class);
            startService(inte2);
        }
    };
}
```

Please help me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Any message in logcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not started your thread. put this code in your second method.

```
 t2.start();
```